# Can I disable animation for Xcode-UI-Tests?

Tags: ios, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

I am using Xcode7 to write UITest, the problem is I need to wait for all the steps to happen before I validate the actual result. This takes a lot of time with all with view controller pushing/presenting/dimissing.

Is there a way through which I can disable the animation while writing the test?

Answer (score 32):

You can disable animations for the entire app with:

```
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
```

This will carry over to running your UI Tests as well. Note that this must be called from the *application code*, not the tests.

Comment: What about SwiftUI?